# Is it possible to not use namespaces in some classies? I'm in trouble with autoload

Tags: php

I'm working with a old project. Classies have no namespacies.

Path structure:

```
-container         // Container
--app
----model          // all classies without namespace
----model_common   // all classies used by other two projects without namespace
------Rede         // new librarie with namespace
--------Exception
--------Service
----view
----controller
```

spl_autoload_register function is in a file named init_client.php, inside app path:

```
define('M_CMN', CLI_APP. 'model_common/');    // $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/model_common/'
define('M_CLI', CLI_APP. 'model/');           //  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/model/'

function autoload_client($class){
    $path_and_class = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class); // May case there is a namespace
    
    if (file_exists(M_CMN . "{$path_and_class}.php")):      // First local to find class
        require_once M_CMN . "{$path_and_class}.php";
        
    elseif (file_exists(M_CLI . "{$path_and_class}.php")):
        require_once M_CLI . "{$path_and_class}.php";
   
    else :
        ErrorFunction("Class {$path_and_class} was not found.",ERROR_1);
    endif;
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload_client');
```

Example:

$consult = new DealConsult;          // app/model
$consult->checkTransaction('123')    // It will use Rede\Store, Rede\Environment and Rede\eRede classies

Error: Class Rede/Store was not found. But file $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/model/Rede/Store.php' exist.

DealConsult.php class:

```
use Rede\Store;
use Rede\Environment;
use Rede\eRede;

class DealConsult {
    public function checkTransaction($cod) {
            $this->store = new Rede\Store($_SESSION['trans']['id_filiacao'], $_SESSION['trans']['token'], Rede\Environment::sandbox());

            $this->transaction = (new Rede\eRede($this->store))->getByReference($cod);

            printf("Autorization status: %s\n", $this->transaction->getAuthorization()->getStatus());
    }
```

What am I not getting understand? I'm learning namespacies recently as well as PSR-4 defaults.

Comment: When you import a class (e.g. `use Rede\Store`) then you can refer to the alias (i.e. the class name whitout namespace). So try `$this->store = new Store(...`
See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: I try it, Mr. @schmauch.
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Rede\Store' not found in /home/test-server/Site_Projects/mysite/app/model/DealConsult.php:47 
Stack trace: 
    #0 /home/test-server/Site_Projects/mysite/app/model/DealConsult.php(36): DealConsult->check()
    #1 /home/test-server/Site_Projects/mysite/app/controller/pages/closedeal.php(58):DealConsult->checkTransaction() 
    #2 /home/test-server/Site_Projects/mysite/index.php(31): include('/home/test-server/S...') 
    #3 {main} thrown in /home/test-server/Site_Projects/mysite/app/model/DealConsult.php on line 47

Comment: It look like the file was included correctly but it's missing a namespace declaration. Make sure, the first line of the file "Rede/Store.php" is `namespace Rede;` and the class declaration is `class Store`.

Comment: Good morning @schmauch. DealConsult.php is in a above directory, so I don't used the namespace Rede in it.

Comment: When you want to instantiate a class `Rede\Store` then there must be a class `Store` in the namespace `Rede`. Otherwise the class won't be found even if the file is included.

Comment: Yes, the class Store is there, Mr. @schmauch . This is the problem that I'm not getting solve.

Comment: have you tried to add `namespace Rede;` as first line in Store.php? This is necessary. Otherwise there is no class that can be referenced by `Rede\Store` as you ar trying.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) to automatically load all the classes. In your `composer.json` file, you need to have:

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Rede\\": "container/app/model_common/"
            // Add as many classes as you need here in this map...
        }
    }
}
```

After that, run:

```sh
compose dump-autoload --optimize
```

Finally, include `vendor/autoload.php` where necessary.

Comment: Thank you, @msrumon, but this project run in a shared server and it have no composer. It's a old project

Comment: That's not true. "Composer" is definitely installed, maybe you don't have access to the terminal or you can't SSH into the server. Either way, you can run the command locally and SFTP the generated files in the server.

Comment: We ask to support of our shared server plan and they affirm is not possible use composer.

Comment: Try this: put `'<pre>' . shell_exec('composer') . '</pre>'` in a PHP file and load it from the browser.

Comment: Good morning @msrumon. I tryed the command '<pre>' . shell_exec('composer') . '</pre>' but nothing was printed.

Comment: Weird! I tried that in one of my servers, and no output there as well. Anyway, you can FTP files in the server, no? You can setup a CI/CD pipeline which will create the autoloader and copy the generated files in the server.